# How to add color based on height of a single geometry nodes mesh

Tags: animation, materials, shaders, geometry-nodes, shader-nodes

[image: IMG]

what can i do to get a effect like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F1kBax6Z8s4 . i have made the animation in geometry nodes . how can i then affect the opacity of the single letters according to the position on the y axis

(note: this is in blender 3.0.0 branch D11522)

Comment: you could do it in the shader editor....

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/81vlZ.png if i did something like this it just affects the position of the whole object is changed . how can i do it

Answer (score -1):

Add Geometry node instead of Object info. You can also use a Math>>Divide node to extend the range.
[image]

Comment: i think this is more related to geometry nodes i dont to to have a gradient but a solid colors on the individual islands i think i need to output one of the vectors from geometry nodes to the material editor